# Why <button /> does not apply -webkit-appearance: button with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap 4 applies these styles :

```
button, html [type="button"], [type="reset"], [type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
```

So i expect these to have the same style :

```
<a class="btn" type="button"> Button </a>

<button class="btn"> Button </button>
```

But `-webkit-appearance: button` seems to do nothing on `<button>` if styled with bootstrap (in chrome at least).

Can someone explains this behaviour ?

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Dyo/pen/qxdNwN).

**Edit :** I found that this : `border: 1px solid transparent; border-radius: 0.25rem;` is cancelling the `-webkit-appearance: button;` visual style.

It seems there's a conflict between the native `-webkit-appearance: button;`, the `-webkit-appearance: button;` applied by bootstrap and `border: 1px solid transparent;`.

The question now is why it only cancels the visual style of the `<button />` even by giving `-webkit-appearance: button;` a higher priority (by doing `<button type="button">`) ?
As i can see in dev tools, bootstrap's `-webkit-appearance: button;` has priority over the native one and replace it, so it should be the same behaviour as `type="button"` on any other html tag.

Answer (score 1):

`-webkit-appearance: button` is the *default* value for that property in Chrome.

Setting a property to a value it already has will never have any effect.

Comment: Yes but my question is why this "visually disappear" when i add class="btn" to it ?

Comment: When you assign ``-webkit-appearance: button;`` to an element, it will be designed with a platform-appropriate styling. How this styling looks like, strongly depends on the platform you are using. Maybe the styling is just not what you are expecting?

Comment: I can take some screenshot if you can't see this as I do but I have the same behaviour on windows chrome and android chrome.

Comment: The question you asked was not "Why does the `<button>` look different from the other elements?", it was "Why doesn't `-webkit-appearance: button` apply to `<button>` elements?". The answer is: It **does** apply, it just isn't sufficient to make the elements look identical by itself.